# How to prove a sum using the Fundamental Theorem of Summations?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

I need to show that the sum of the first $n$ odd integers is equal to $n^2$ by using the Fundamental Theorem of Summations and I know that

$n^2 = \sum_{k=1}^n 2n-1 = F(n+1)-F(k)$,

however I can't seem to determine what the antidifference of the general term would be so I can prove the relation. What am I missing? I'm going insane!

Comment: If you don't have to use that theorem, by the way, there's an easy picture proof. Draw on squared paper a square of side length $n$. You can make the square of side length $n+1$ by adding $n$ mini-squares along the right-hand edge, and $n$ mini-squares along the top edge, and one mini-square at the top-right corner.

Comment: Let $F(n)=n^2$.  Then 
\begin{align}
F(n)=F(0)+\sum_{k=1}^n (F(k)-F(k-1)).
\end{align}
But $F(k)-F(k-1)=2k-1$.

Comment: @user254433 can I use $F(k)-F(k-1)$ rather than $F(n+1)-F(k)$? I don't see how that would be equivalent? Please elaborate

Comment: @PatrickStevens unfortunately, I do need to use that theorem. Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: I think using $F(n+1)-F(k)$ might be a mistake:  isn't $k$ an index of summation?  The identity using $F(k)-F(k-1)$ comes from the terms in the summation cancelling: e.g. $F(2)=F(0)+(F(1)-F(0))+(F(2)-F(1))$.

Comment: @user254433 My course text explains that that is the result of the telescoping series. These are the definitions it gives that I need to use:

$\Delta{F}(x) = F(x+1)-F(x)=f(x)$

for the definition of the antidifference and 

$\sum_{k=a}^b f(x)=F(b+1)-F(a)$

for the Fundamental Theorem of Summations

Comment: These definitions are correct, but the equation in your original post is not, since it doesn't match with these definitions.

Comment: @user254433 Oh! I think I'm starting to see what you mean now. Thanks for pointing that out to me, that helps a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer provided in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{k=1}^n(2k-1)=\sum_{k=1}^n(k^2-(k-1)^2)=n^2-0^2=n^2$$